# C# Flush click event queue

Tags: c#, events, button

I have problem in C# that when I click multiple times a button then it generates
a queue of events and blocks my application. Every click sends CAN message and it takes some time.
What I want to achieve is to flush that queue to be sure that every 500ms only one message will be send.

Best,
Chris

Comment: Why not disabling the button for some blocking-period (e.g. 500ms), so you won't need to mess around with event queue?

Comment: Or log the time of last send & exit the event if within 500ms.

Comment: disable the button after the first click, so it can't be clicked multiple times.